# How to display an image offline using Famo.us

Tags: image, uri, blob, famo.us

How can you display an image that can be used offline using Famo.us?

A Famo.us Image surface sets it's content based on an image URL.  However, when offline, this URL will not work.  I have tried using an HTTP request and converting the buffer to a Blob and then creating a URI for the Blob:

```
    // bytes = request.buffer of HTTP request
    // Make a Blob from the bytes
    var blob = new Blob([bytes], {type: 'image/jpg'});

    // Use createObjectURL to make a URL for the blob
    imageURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    //Use Famo.us image surface API to display the image (http://famo.us/docs/api/latest/surfaces/ImageSurface)
    imageSurface.setContent(imageURL);
```

This does not throw any warning or errors but displays a broken image.  Any suggestions?  I want to display an image even when I am offline, but when I reconnect I will request for the newest image uploaded.

Comment: [@mwilli31](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4686086/mwilli31) using `Blob` will require `FileReader` and gets somewhat messy for what you need.  Are you loading the image into the Blob using the URL?  I have a solution, but does not use the Blob.

Comment: I am loading the image into the Blob after I have received the image data bytes from a HTTP request.  The canvas answer looks promising, I will try that out.

Comment: The nice thing about the canvas solution, is you can add stuff like watermarks, etc to images for rendering without having to add them to the image themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ImageSurface` in `Famo.us` can take a url to the image or the base-64 encoded data.

#### Using `Blob`:

Use the file reader to `readAsDataURL`

```
 var reader  = new FileReader();

  reader.onloadend = function () {
    imageURL = reader.result;
  }

  reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
```

#### Using `Canvas`:

There are plenty of ways to get the encoded base-64 data.  `Canvas` has another way to get this string for you.

#### [Example jsBin Here](http://jsbin.com/wahora/1/edit?js,output)

Using the example snippet below, you can see how you can use `Canvas.toDataURL`.

```js
  var image = new Image();
  image.crossOrigin = 'anonymous'; // only needed for CORS, not needed for same domain.

  // create an empty canvas element
  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  var canvasContext = canvas.getContext("2d");

  image.onload = function () {

    //Set canvas size is same as the picture
    canvas.width = image.width;
    canvas.height = image.height;

    // draw image into canvas element
    canvasContext.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);

    // get canvas contents as a data URL (returns png format by default)
    imageURL  = canvas.toDataURL();
  };

  image.src = 'http://code.famo.us/assets/famous_logo.png';
```

Comment: This works! The only thing I needed to change was add the image.src to be before the image.onload function.  I received a broken image otherwise.

Comment: I have had some fun with it myself.  Glad it helped you out!